# Can not create Force.com site via Ant tool

Tags: force.com-sites, metadata-api, ant

Just tried to deploy new salesforce custom site via Metadata API (ant tool) and also tried Eclipse but target org returns the following message:

*The Force.com Site subdomain has not been set in the organization*

[image]

I have modified Metadata and specified username and unique sub-domain name. Example of Custom Site metadata file is below:

Is it generally possible to create Force.com site via Metadata API - did not find any evidence in documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sites.htm

Also can not find Force.com Site among unsupported components

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm

Comment: Hi Yuri, 
You can definitely deploy a site via ant as per Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_website_api_overview.htm&language=en_US). Can you share the file you are trying to deploy?

Comment: It sounds like it's telling you that the subdomain needs to be configured in the Org before your can deploy the site. That's something which isn't part of the metadata and requires point & click configuration in the org itself first before you do your deployment. The site domain, etc has to exist for you to deploy to.

Comment: @AmrIbrahim - the link to the example of site metadata file I am trying to deploy is below: https://gist.github.com/yury-vrp/9ccc5835a3879511b5d4#file-mysite-xml

Comment: @Yury Do you have your domain already setup?
If not you might want to follow the format in this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sites.htm)

Comment: @AmrIbrahim No, I do not. The idea is to create a script that will preform full configuration of force.com site from command line (including domain registration). Isn't it possible to register domain via ant (Metadata)?

Comment: If that is the case, then your xml is missing the domain part. Refer to the link in my previous comment and see how domain is used.
`<customWebAddresses>
      <domainName>www.testing123.com</domainName>
      <primary>true</primary>
</customWebAddress>`

Comment: @AmrIbrahim It looks like the code you provided is to crate custom alias for salesforce's force.com site. 
So, it seems, there is no any way to create force.com domain using Metadata API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not find a way to register force.com site domain through Metadata API/Migration tool.

Most likely in order to be able to deploy Site configuration you need to register your force.com site sub-domain first, manually, through salesforce interface (see screenshot attached)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using ant to get retrieve a site's metadata is useful even if you can't turn-around and use it for anything else.

It doesn't seem it can be used for creating a new site in a target org, and it doesn't appear to be a way to update an existing site with new values.

If anyone does figure out how to use it to update sites in multiple orgs (usually sandboxes), let me know.