# Not able to add public site to unlocked package

Tags: unlocked-package

I have public site metadata in my local project.

I have created an unlocked package and now I am trying to create a first package version and face an issue:

[Site Name]: The Force.com Site subdomain has not been set in the organization.

Dev Hub, which is connected for version creation has an appropriate subdomain.
What I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291106/96007) helps

Comment: Based on your comment, I may have misunderstood that metadata. My apologies. Still, part of my answer still stands: whatever is in your Dev Hub is not part of your Unlocked Package. You must specify things like subdomains in your package metadata, and not rely on any configuration in the Dev Hub org (unless you plan on making it an Org Dependent package).

Comment: Got it. I am a bit confused about how can I specify subdomains in my metadata. All I have is Site metadata and when I push it to scratch org, the Site is set up properly and everything works as expected. But with a package, there is an issue mentioned above.